# Geary crashing when looking through emails

Tags: pantheon-mail, crash

Geary crashes after clicking through a few e-mails on the left panel.Not sure why,This hasn't been happening for very long.

Comment: got the same problem recently ! I didn't notice any update for it..

Comment: Open a terminal and type ~$ geary --version Make sure this is the latest version. (currently 0.10.0) Run geary through terminal to see why it crashes. This will give us more insformation. post result here ~$ geary

Comment: got the same problem recently too. Geary version is 0.10.0 Geary crashes when opening (and previewing) a new HTML e-mail, like a newsletter. (geary:4722): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed (geary:4722): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed (geary:4722): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed (geary:4722): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module" (firefox:4

Comment: I have reported this bug. If you click on the "this bug affects me too" button, it might get more attention! https://bugs.launchpad.net/geary/+bug/1567050

Comment: I don't know if reporting bugs on geary will be useful, because elementary forked geary to pantheon mail and development on geary has stopped for quite some time now. Maybe wait a while until the next version of elementary is released (codename Loki) with Pantheon Mail.

Comment: I have the same problem! I use Geary 0.10.0 Most of the time freezes, than crashes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4355)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a temporary reprieve from this issue by disabling the 'Always show remote images' option in Reading preferences, it was driving me nuts!!

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: For those, who can't get to the preference panel, you may use the shortcut `ctrl + e` to get to it, before the app crashes!